# What am I doing wrong? Edit table data in form

Tags: php, database, forms, html-table, edit

I have a table with a edit link and a delete button on each row. Delete button is working fine but the edit link I don´t know what I´m doing wrong with!

Clicking the edit link for a specific row it leads to edit page with the form BUT the data is not filled out. There is no error message... I can see up in the URL field that it´s the correct id for the chosen movie.

What am I missing? Do I need to write any queries etc on the edit page as well? I did try and make it a require page so when clicking on the edit button the edit form pops up on the index page. But I couldn't manage to do that.

I know I'm using mysql functions which are outdated, and I have yet to add SQL protection.

**The database is called moviedata and has 2 tables.**

- Table 1 is called: movies

  - Fields/columns (5): **id** (primary key, AI),   ****title**  , **release_year**,**   ****genre_id**, **director****
- Table 2 is called: categories

  - Fields/columns (2): **genre_id** (primary key, AI), **genre**

There is a relation (Foreign key) between genre_id (primary key,    table 2) and genre_id (table 1).

**index.php code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>My movie library</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mall.css" />

</head>

<body>
<?php 

    require 'connect.inc.php';

    if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $query = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id=".$id." LIMIT 1";

        if (!mysql_query($query, $sql))
            echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>".
            mysql_error() . "<br><br>";
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM movies m INNER JOIN categories c ON m.genre_id = c.genre_id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed:" .mysql_error()) ;
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    echo '<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Release year</th><th>Genre</th><th>Director</th><th>Update</th><th>Delete</th></tr>';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td>' .$row["title"] . '</td>' ;
    echo '<td>' .$row["release_year"] . '</td>' ;
    echo '<td>' .$row["genre_id"] . '</td>' ;
    echo '<td>' .$row["director"] . '</td>' ;
    echo '<td>'."<a href='edit_movie.php?edit=" . $row["id"] . "'>Edit</a>".'</td>';
    echo '<td><form action="index.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'. $row["id"] .'" /> 
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" /></form>
                </td></tr>' ;
    }
    echo '</table>'; 

?>

</body>

</html>
```

**And here is the code on edit_movie.php page. The edit page with the form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>My movie library</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mall.css" />

</head>

<body>

<?php

require 'connect.inc.php';


//close MySQL
mysql_close($sql);

?>

<p>Edit movie</p>
<div id="form_column">
<form action="edit_movie.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php if (isset($row["id"])) ?>" /> <br>
Title:<br> <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if (isset($row["title"])) { echo $row["title"];} ?>" /> <br>
Release Year:<br> <input type="text" name="release_year" value="<?php if (isset($row["release_year"])) { echo $row["release_year"];} ?>" /> <br>
Director:<br> <input type="text" name="director" value="<?php if (isset($row["director"])) { echo $row["director"];} ?>" /> <br><br>
Select genre:
<br>
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="1" checked />Action<br>
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="2" />Comedy<br>
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="3" />Drama<br>
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="4" />Horror<br>
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="5" />Romance<br>
<br> <input type="radio" name="genre_id" value="6" />Thriller<br><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

**The database connection is in a separate connect.inc.php file which is required at the top of these files. The code in the connect.inc.php file you can see below:**

```
<?php


//connect to MySQL
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$sql = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
//select database
mysql_select_db("moviedata");

?>
```

Comment: have you tried printing each `UPDATE` query and testing it directly against the database?

Comment: @Killrawr Hi, thanks for your response! No I haven´t... I did try and make a form with hidden fields for edit button as I did for delete button. But I kept getting error messages and I did use UPDATE `movies` SET ... etc in a query. I couldn´t figure out how to write the UPDATE correctly I think.

Comment: try `'UPDATE table SET column = "value" WHERE column = "anothervalue"'`

Comment: Also look into [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), your current code is open to SQL Injection attacks (So I'd be wary of that).

Comment: Thank you! So if I were to just test the UPDATE query is the only thing I need to write

Comment: cool, um check out my answer for a description of what I'd recommend.

Comment: Sorry my comment was incomplete... So if I were to just test the UPDATE query is the only thing I need to write $query UPDATE movies SET id etc to test it? Or do I need to write and if statements etc as well? What is the first value of the column? is it id = "id"? "anothervalue"? Is it for example like this: UPDATE movies SET id = "id" where id = "$id"'?

Comment: okay say I have a table called `movies` and i want to update its `title` and this movie has a Primary key called `ID`, and the movie I want to update is at `id` 5, I would write.. `UPDATE movies SET title = "Iron Man 3" WHERE id = 5`.

Comment: That worked and I can edit data this way! But here I wrote the id for the movie, what I don´t get is how to get the correct id for the movie being clicked on... I´ll try the code below that you suggested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code is kinda mess, because **it's not even procedural**. **You're making problems for yourself. Really.**

There are some things you must remember when developing an application using PHP:

### Never print/echo html tags

. 
Try to avoid this as much as possible because this makes your code unmaintainable and unreadable. Use an alternate syntax instead.

That is, PHP should be used as a **template engine** itself, not "generate" the ones.

### Separate responsibilities. Clearly and wisely

A functions which connect to a database should not be used in a presentation (in this case - HTML). You'd create one file which is responsible for database, another one which is responsible for data manipulation(such as DELETE, CREATE, UPDATE operations) and the like.

### Don't forget about SQL injection & XSS

Never trust data you get from superglobals like `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE` and `$_REQUEST`. At minimum, `mysql_real_escape_string()` should be used for each dynamic input you are going to deal with.

Generally speaking, [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) allows to execute any JavaScript code via aforementioned superglobals as well as injecting another html code within general markup. In order to prevent this, basically `htmlentities()` would be great enough here.

### Wrap things into a function

So instead of doing this,

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM movies WHERE id=".$id." LIMIT 1";
```

You should re-write it like so:

```
function delete_movie_by_id($id){
   return mysql_unbuffered_query(sprintf("DELETE FROM `movies` WHERE id='%s' LIMIT 1", mysql_real_escape_string($id)));
}

if ( isset($_POST['delete'], $_POST['id']) ){

   delete_movie_by_id($_POST['id']); // it's safe & readable now
}
```

### Learn about OOP and switch to PDO

Well, a procedural code is not the way to go when you're developing something like this. Next time you will be writing something, you'd really start using both PDO for database access and OOP.

---

**I could go on, but it's better to stop now, and switch back to your original question.**

Well, you didn't say which error exactly you get. For example, do you know if `mysql_select()` returns FALSE ( === failure on database selection), this won't terminate the script!? According to code you've posted, you do not "track it" in any way.

**First**

So, connect.inc.php should look like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // <-- Important!

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

if ( ! mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password) ){
   die(sprintf('Cannot connect to MySQL server because of "%s"', mysql_error()));
}

//select database
if ( ! mysql_select_db("moviedata") ){
  die(sprintf('Cannot select a database, because of "%s"', mysql_error()))
}
```

**Second**

In edit_movie.php page, this code block, isn't required at all. The connection will be closed automatically when a script terminates.

So just remove this:

```
<?php

require 'connect.inc.php';

//close MySQL
mysql_close($sql);
```

**Third**

In that `edit_movie.php`, you're clearly asking: `if ( isset($row['some_column']) )...`, but what is it all about? Where's the `$row` itself? it wasn't defined anywhere, so you won't get what you expect. Here:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php if (isset($row["id"])) ?>" /> <br>
Title:<br> <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if (isset($row["title"])) { echo $row["title"];} ?>" /> <br>
Release Year:<br> <input type="text" name="release_year" value="<?php if (isset($row["release_year"])) { echo $row["release_year"];} ?>" /> <br>
Director:<br> <input type="text" name="director" value="<?php if (isset($row["director"])) { echo $row["director"];} ?>" /> <br><br>
```

Okay, that's enough.

Consider, rewriting your application like this:

File: `movie.inc.php`

```
require_once('connect.inc.php');

/**
 * Fetch all movies from a table
 * @return array on success, FALSE on failure
 */
function get_all_movies(){

   $query = "SELECT * FROM movies m INNER JOIN categories c ON m.genre_id = c.genre_id";

   $result = mysql_query($query);

   if ( ! $result ){ 
     return false;
   } else {
     $return = array();

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $return[] = array('director' => $row['director'], 'genre_id' => $row['genre_id'], 'release_year' => $row['release_year'], 'title' => $row['title'], 'id' => $row['id']); 
     }
       return $return;
   }
}

function delete_movie_by_id($id){
  // I already wrote this, see above
}
```

File `index.php`

```
<?php

require('movie.inc.php');

if ( isset($_GET['delete']) && isset($_GET['id']) ){
   if ( delete_movie_by_id($_POST['id']) ){ //it's 100% safe
       die('Movie has been removed. Refresh the page now'); // or the like
   } else {
      // could not - handle here
   }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>My movie library</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mall.css" />

</head>
<body>

<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Release year</th>
  <th>Genre</th><th>Director</th>
  <th>Update</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
 </tr>

  <?php  foreach (get_all_movies() as $index => $row) : ?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['title'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['release_year']; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['genre_id'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['director'];?></td>
     <td><a href='<?php printf('edit_movie.php?edit=%s', $row['id']);?>>Edit</a></td>
     <td>
      <form action="index.php" method="GET">
              <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" /> 
              <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
      </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm tired now, hope you can get the core idea from this answer.

---

**UPDATE**

There are basic steps to make a movie "editable" :

1) You grab the data you are going to edit (from the table)
2) You send edited data back to the server (php script)
3) You validate the input
4) You run `UPDATE` query

That's all.

So it would be similar to this (File: **edit_movie.php**):

```
<?php

require_once('movie.inc.php');


/**
 * Grabs the movie data by its id
 * 
 * @param $id A movie id 
 * @return array on succes, FALSE if $id is wrong
 */
function get_movie_by_id($id){

   $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `enter_movie_table_name_here` WHERE `id` = '%s' LIMIT 1", mysql_real_escape_string($id));

   $result = mysql_query($query);

   if ( ! $result ){
       return false;
   } else {
       return $result;
   }
}


function update_movie_by_id($id, array $data){

    $query = sprintf("UPDATE `the_movie_table` 
              SET `director` ='%s',
                  `genre_id` = '%s',
                  `relase_year` ='%s',
                  `title` = '%s' WHERE `id` = '%s' LIMIT 1"),

                   mysql_real_escape_string($data['director']),
                   mysql_real_escape_string($data['genre_id']),
                   mysql_real_escape_string($data['relase_year']),
                   mysql_real_escape_string($data['title']),
                   mysql_real_escape_string($id) );

    // not mysql_query() !!! but this
    return mysql_unbuffered_query($query); 
}


// Next thing is to get an id by query string,
// So if it was /movide_edit.php?id=1
// then id we have is 1

// So we need to handle that right now


if ( isset($_GET['id']) ){

   $movie = get_movie_by_id($_GET['id']);

   if ( ! $movie ){ // <- make sure that id isn't fake
      die(sprintf('Invalid movie id "%s"', $_GET['id']));
   }

} else {

   die('Please supply an id you want to edit'); // <- this makes sence
}


// Ok, we'll reserve this block for an update

if ( !empty($_POST) ){ // This will run when user clicked on Save button

      if ( update_movie_by_id($_POST['id'], array(

              'director' => $_POST['director'],
              'genre_id' => $_POST['genre_id'],
              'relase_year' => $_POST['relase_year'],
              'title'       => $_POST['title']

         )) ){

             die('Movie has been updated');
         } else {

          die('Could not update a movie for some wicked reason..');
         }

}


// That's all. Now it can:

//1) Fetch the data
//2) Edit accordingly 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!--

This is kinda quick and dirty form
You need to fix this later

-->

<body>

  <form method="POST">

     <label for="title">Title</label>
     <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $movie['title']; " />

     <!--
           Add another elements this way..
      -->

    <button type="submit">Save</button>  

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WOW thanks for your effort and input! I´m gonna try out the stuff you wrote!

Comment: I can't be sure if this 100% works (bcz I didn't test it), but that is not a point here. The point here is a core idea you need to understand. (like separation etc etc etc)

Comment: Got it! :) Really appreciate you took the time!

Comment: Hi, I just tried the code but it´s still the exact same problem. The data is not printed out in the edit form:/ I put the html edit form in the index file underneath the php code since the other files where inc files...

Comment: @Karolina Oh no! 1) Please don't put the html in `index.php`. That's entirely wrong. If other files are "inc" files - it does not mean, you should include everything through the index. A `require_once()` should be used instead at the top of `edit_movie.php` 2) Fetch the data from a table in `movie_edit.php` then echo it... it's so easy :)

Comment: I think my problem is what you are mentioning, that the data is not being defined in the edit movie form. I just can´t get around how to get it to work... Also deleting a movie doesn´t work now, it says Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\test\index.php on line 6

Comment: oh yeah, replace this `delete_movie_by_id($_POST['id']` with `delete_movie_by_id($_GET['id']` it was a typo, my bad :( If the rest works then you need only to fetch the data from a table for `movie_edit.php`. If you can't I'll update the answer with some explanations.

Comment: Ah now deleting is working! But yeah the fetching data is the major problem I´ve been trying to solve...

Comment: Thanks again for your long input with comments. I´ve really learned some good stuff on how to structure things up! I still got that problem with fetching the movie information into the edit form which is driving me crazy so if you can help on that it would be much appreciated!:)

Comment: Oh can you please help me out??? Please pretty please! I´m going bananas! I just can´t get it to work and it´s the 3rd day I´m sitting with this. I can´t figure out how to write a function to fetch the id and edit a movie in the edit form. The data will just not follow into the form:(

Comment: ok :) Also, note, this approach is extremely outdated. Nobody no longer uses `form` submission. Learn `jquery` and ajax. This would allow you to update the movies without page refresh, so that your app will more friendly and beautiful as well. Take care :)

Comment: Thanks, noted! I´m getting there soon:) I´m such a rookie with php and taking everything one step at a time at the moment:) You explained stuff really well!